# C Pointer Program Swapping of String Using Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code sample, can someone tell me why `str1_ptr` and `str2_ptr` are declared with type `char **` instead of `char *` (e.g. `char **str1_ptr` instead of `char *str1_ptr`) in the signature of the `swap1()` function?

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Swaps strings by swapping pointers */

void swap1(char **str1_ptr, char **str2_ptr) {
    char *temp = *str1_ptr;

    *str1_ptr = *str2_ptr;
    *str2_ptr = temp;
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = "geeks";
    char *str2 = "forgeeks";

    swap1(&str1, &str2);

    printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The `swap1()` function swaps the two strings.

Comment: you need a pointer the the type you want to swap, in this case the type is char*, so a pointer to char* is char**

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the values of the `str1` and `str2` pointers declared in `main()` from `swap1()`.

To accomplish this, you need to be passed a pointer on each of these pointers in `swap1()`.

A string (i.e. char array) pointer in C has type `char *`, so a pointer on such a pointer (pointer on a string pointer) has type `char **`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at how the values of the variables `str1` and `str2` look after the lines

```
char *str1 = "geeks";
char *str2 = "forgeeks";
```

it will look something like:

```
                                  Address 1 (block of memory for "geeks")
                                  |
|<--  str1   ->|                  v
+--------------+                  +--------------------------+
| Address 1    |                  | g | e | e | k | s | '\0' | 
+--------------+                  +--------------------------+

                                  Address 2 (block of memory for "forgeeks")
                                  |
|<--  str2   ->|                  v
+--------------+                  +--------------------------------------+
| Address 2    |                  | f | o | r | g | e | e | k | s | '\0' | 
+--------------+                  +--------------------------------------+
```

Since you want to swap where `str1` and `str2` point to, you are interested in making the necessary changes so that the value of `str1` is `Address 2` and the value of `str2` is `Address 1`:

```
|<--  str1   ->|
+--------------+
| Address 2    |
+--------------+                    

|<--  str2   ->|
+--------------+
| Address 1    |
+--------------+
```

You can do that only if you pass the addresses of `str1` and `str2` to `swap1`. You accomplish that by using `swap1(&str1, &str2);`.

Since the type of `str1` and `str2` is `char*`, the type of `&str1` and `&str2` is `char**`. That's you have to use:

```
void swap1(char **str1_ptr, char **str2_ptr)
```

instead of

```
void swap1(char *str1, char *str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `void swap1(char *str1_ptr, char *str2_ptr)`

Your pointer is **passed by value**, and this code copies, then overwrites the copy. So the original pointer is untouched.

Too Fix this - pass a pointer to a pointer so that changes done in function can be **reflected** in main as you want it to be swapped.